# How to group a subset of Included Changes

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

When I view my pending changes, every file must appear in either Included Changes or Excluded Changes. This is consistently a problem for me as oftentimes I only want to check in (or shelve) a subset of the files in the Included Changes. The obvious answer is to exclude those I don't want, but that doesn't work well because I oftentimes have many other Excluded changes, and then I can't easily find those I just excluded among the sea of other changes. For example:

- My solution contains 24 projects.
- I have 100 excluded changes.
- I am working on something and have 20 included changes.
- Someone walks to my desk and asks for help with something. I forget to suspend my work and just start helping them. We get into it and work for a bit, fix the problem, I've edited 2 more files, and now I have 22 included changes. I want to check in the 2 files I just modified.

The problem is there is no good way to separate those 2 files into a group (or the 20 I want to exclude). If I exclude the 20 files I don't want to check in, then when I'm done I have to go into my excluded files and find them all again to include, but they are interspersed among the other 100 files. I feel like there must be a simple way to do this?

Ideally there would be a way to group a set of excluded changes with a custom name. (Like you can do with pending changesets in Perforce.)

**Update:** I think there is a more elegant answer which is similar to the proposed answers. The key lies in my statement above: "I forget to suspend my work..." Well, since the set of files you want to checkin is presumably small by comparison, just exclude those files, then suspend it now, then re-include the files and perform the checkin, then resume. I just did this now and found it a little smoother than the solutions below. But, if you would need to exclude many files and hunting around for them among the sea of excluded files would be difficult, then the accepted answer seems like the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Team explorer doesn't support group include/exclude changes.

You could vote this user voice about group changes in Excluded Changes: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16058794-group-changes-in-included-excluded-changes .

In your scenario, you have 22 changes. 2 changes(A) you want check in now. The remaining 20 changes(B), you don't want to check in). As a workaround:

1. create a shelveset(Shelveset1) for the whole 22 changes(A+B).
2. Undo the B.
3. Check in A.
4. Find Shelveset1 and exclude A.
5. Unshelf Shelveset1.

Answer (score 1):

Once you finished working on the 20 changes, you can shelve the changes (pending changes->shelve), so it will appear in **included changes**, drag it to **excluded changes**.

Afterwards, you can work on the 2 more changes, no matter you want to **check in** or **shelve** the changes, it has no effect on the 20 changes.